# Creating an ActionListener to search through TextArea of NotepadGUI using MVC

Tags: java, model-view-controller, user-interface, highlight, actionlistener

Here is the VIEW of my notepad application. I need to create a controller that searches through the textarea in the centerPanel. I have a JButton defined, as well as a textfield, and want the user to be able to type text into the field and press the button to highlight the searched text. I have all my ActionListeners defined in a new class.

```java
public NotepadView() {
        super();
        //WINDOW
        setSize (750,500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Chad's Notepad");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        //CENTER PANEL
        centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        centerPanel.add(textArea);
        add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        scrollPaneText = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        add(scrollPaneText);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setFont(new Font("Garamond", Font.PLAIN, 18));

        //BOTTOM PANEL
        bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        setButton = new JButton("Find");
        textField = new JTextField("EnterText");
        bottomPanel.add(setButton);
        bottomPanel.add(textField);
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //MENU BAR
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        fileMenu = new JMenu("File");   
        newItem = new JMenuItem("New");
        openItem = new JMenuItem("Open");
        saveItem = new JMenuItem("Save");
        closeItem = new JMenuItem("Close");
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        fileMenu.add(newItem);
        fileMenu.add(openItem); 
        fileMenu.add(saveItem); 
        fileMenu.add(closeItem);
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        newItem.addActionListener(new NewMenuCommand(textArea));
        openItem.addActionListener(new OpenMenuCommand(textArea));
        closeItem.addActionListener(new QuitMenuCommand());
        saveItem.addActionListener(new SaveMenuCommand(textArea));
    }
}
```

//ActionListener new class for Button

```
    public class ButtonCommand implements ActionListener {
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private String hText;
    int ind = 0;
    private String findString;


    public ButtonCommand (JTextArea ta){
        textArea = ta;
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
         hText = textArea.getText();
         findString=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Find   what","Find",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
         ind = hText.indexOf(findString,0);
         textArea.setCaretPosition(ind);
         textArea.setSelectionStart(ind);
         int a = ind+findString.length();
         textArea.setSelectionEnd(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is it you're asking about? How to highlight the text? How to perform the search? How to create/design a controller? Is the goal to learn how to do so (homework?), or are the means inconsequential? [You could also argue that Java SWING components are both views and controllers.](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/architecture/)

Comment: Thanks for responding. My goal is for a user to enter text into the textfield and highlight the text in the text area. I found an example on [Highlighting] (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TextFieldDemoProject/src/components/TextFieldDemo.java) but, I need to implement it in its own class. I've tried a bunch of different options, but none of them seem to work. This is for a homework but, I would like to learn how to do it for future reference.

Comment: It's still rather unclear what you need help with, I've understood your goal but not what you need help with. You'll probably get more/faster help by posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).